# What size of activeDataFrame?

Tags: arcpy, data-frame

I want to write a script in Python for ArcGIS to search for the size of an activeDataFrame (DataFrame) in meters (scale)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different sizes attached to the data frame. After getting the active data frame:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
```

There is the size of the element on the layout:

```
height = df.elementHeight
width = df.elementWidth
```

There is the extent of the data frame from the data view. That is the portion of the data frame shown on the page layout that is in the spatial reference system:

```
ext = df.extent
extWidth = ext.width #width in map units (maxium x coordinate minus minimum x coordinate)
extHeight = ext.height #height = maximum Y coordiante minus minimum Y coordinate)
xmin = ext.XMin #minium x coordinate
#there are properties for XMax YMax and YMin also
```

Finally there is the scale for the data frame as shown in the toolbox 1:xxxxxx

```
scale = df.scale #just the right side of the colon 1:xxxxxx
refscale = df.referenceScale #string of the whole scale '1:xxxxx'
```